# Make folder from part of a filename, and move the files there

Tags: batch-file, command

I've been trying to figure out how to make a dos command that can "see" part of a file name, then create a folder and sort every file which has that part of a file name in it.

Every file name has the following characters (excluding the extension):

3 letters, 5 digits, 1 letter, 1 digit

For example: BBB12345B0

Each letter and number in the file name can vary, but the file name will always have the same build.

What the script is supposed to do is recognize only the 5 digits, then create a folder from those 5 digits and then move those files to that folder.

The following i found on the internet:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do (

if not "%%~fa"=="%~f0" (

md "%%~na" 2>nul

if exist "%%a" move "%%~na.*" "%%~na"

)

)
```

This works great, except that the whole file name is used to create a folder and sort the files. I want the script to do the same thing but only using the 5 digits.

I've tried to work with "tokens" in this script. Also used some other methods but none of them work properly. I'm also not so familiar with this kind of batch scripting.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

try this (may be need change places of '%')

```
md %a:~3,5% 2>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: fixed the batch filename filter.

Test this: if there are zillions of files then it can be optimised for speed.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (
BBB11345B0
BBB12345B0
BBB13345B0
BBB14345B0
BBB15345B0
BBB16345B0
) do type nul >%%a

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do (
   if /i not "%%a"=="%~nx0" (
      echo moving "%%a"
      set "name=%%a"
      md "!name:~3,5!" 2>nul
      move "%%a" "!name:~3,5!" >nul
   )
)
```